# how to call jquery function after redirecting to same page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, header

Let's say after my user fills a form and clicks the submit button, I want the user redirected to the same page with the form and a jquery animation will play. The header function is there to prevent the user from refreshing the page and resubmitting the same data.

UPDATE:
I've decided to use $_SESSION to record the user's session to try to get the jquery animation to play after they get redirected to the same page:

```
<?php
session_start(); 

if (isset ($_POST['submit']))
{
$connect = mysql_connect("","","") or die("Error connecting to db");
mysql_select_db("") or die("Error connecting to db");

$text = $_POST['text'];



mysql_query ("INSERT INTO header VALUES('','$text')");

  $_SESSION['jq']=='a';
    header('Location: header.php');
    die();

}


if($_SESSION['jq']=='a') {
   $_SESSION['jq']='';

echo'
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div").hide(3000);

});
</script>';


}




?>



<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#jquery {border:1px solid black;width:300px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form name="header" action="header.php" method="post">


<input type="text" name="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"    />
</form>
<div id="jquery">this is jquery animation</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, it's exactly that. Has the page reloading anything to do with it, or do you just want to know how to play an animation at all? If so, you *have* to be more specify about what animation you want, or you should change the comment to "Insert some random animation here".

Comment: yeah, it could be any kind of animation

Comment: add a "slick" factor, submit via ajax and use the success callback to fire your animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use like this**

```
if (isset ($_POST['submit']))
{
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO header VALUES('','$text')");

    //redirect to same page that user submitted form from
    header('Location: form.php?jq=a');
    die();
}
if($_GET['jq']=='a') {
   //play animation
   echo'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

       //insert jquery animation code

   });
   </script>';
}
```

**Or**

```
session_start();
if (isset ($_POST['submit']))
{
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO header VALUES('','$text')");

    //redirect to same page that user submitted form from
    //$_SESSION['jq']=='a'; commented for your understanding remove this in your code.
    $_SESSION['jq']='a';
    header('Location: form.php');
    die();
}
if($_SESSION['jq']=='a') {
   $_SESSION['jq']='';
   //play animation
   echo'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

       //insert jquery animation code

   });
   </script>';
}
```

Comment: for the second method with $_SESSION, the data gets sent to the SQL table, but the animation doesn't play. Please help!

Comment: oh k then after submitting to form.php open the view source and check is the script is there... in which page you have this php code? in form.php or its previous file..

Comment: the form action page is in the same location as the php code so form.php has the php code.

Comment: If I do that, I will get "Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent" Please see my updated OP above!

Comment: sorry again, change the == to = before the header function. i have updated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just keep the user on the same page, and process the form submit on the same page (by setting the `action` attribute of the form to the page that the form is on)?

That would deal with the redirection problem. You can then have your jQuery animation code in the original page, and start the animation in a `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` statement.

Comment: well, the header function is to prevent them from refreshing the page and resubmitting the data

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form).

Comment: Maybe you could provide an example?